# How to print elements of a list if we have created a pointer of list class(in c++)

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include<iostream>

#include<list>

using namespace std;

int main(){ 
   
    list<int> *newL;
    newL->push_back(45);
    newL->push_back(25);
    newL->push_back(35);
    newL->push_back(10);
    newL->push_back(20);
    newL->push_back(30);
    newL->push_back(20);
    newL->push_back(10);
}
```

Here, I have  created a list pointer newL, and push_back some elements, please help me how to access these elements, like in vector, we use at(i), i is index

Comment: Read the documentation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: This is UB, you did not allocate any list - just don't use a pointer. List does not support indexing because it is a linked list. Why use list if you want a vector?

Comment: You declared a pointer to a list, but you never allocated memory for it. You need `newL = new list<int>;`

Comment: The documentation also has an example showing how to iterate over the list.

Comment: Also there is a reason why elements of `std::list` cannot be accessed array-like with an index - you might look up the differences between `std::vector` and `std::list`

Comment: Side note: `v.at(i)` includes range checks and exceptions – when you already know that you are in range (typically within loops), then `v.operator[](i)` – in short: `v[i]` (!) – is preferrable (more efficient). Even if you don't know the range an explicit check + `[i]` usually is clearer code than the try/catch approach.

Comment: Before you can access elements of a list, it is necessary to actually create the list.   Your code creates `newL` as an uninitialised pointer.   An uninitialised pointer does not point at a valid list.  Calling `newL->push_back()` therefore gives undefined behaviour.   If you *must* have a pointer (it is actually unnecessary) you need to initialise it so it points at a valid list BEFORE calling `push_back()`.   One way is initialise the pointer at point of declaration (e.g. `list<int> *newL = new list<int>;`).  Another is to assign it (e.g. `list<int> newL;   newL = new list<int>;`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access elements in your code in a list because there is no list in your code. `newL` is just a pointer. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer invokes undefined behavior. Do not use pointers when there is no need for them.

You cannot access elements in a linked list by index, because it is a linked list. You can however iterate from begin till end to access the elements. A range based loop can do that.

```
#include<iostream>   
#include<list>
    
int main(){        
    std::list<int> newL;
    newL.push_back(45);
    newL.push_back(25);
    newL.push_back(35);
    newL.push_back(10);
    newL.push_back(20);
    newL.push_back(30);
    newL.push_back(20);
    newL.push_back(10);
    for (const auto& element : newL) std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy task,
It is all about pointers in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main(){


    std::list<int> *pL= new std::list<int>  { 8, 7, 15, 12, 9 };


    std::cout<<"list size "<<pL->size()<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"add two items"<<std::endl;
    pL->push_back(3);
    pL->push_back(20);

    std::cout<<"list size "<<pL->size()<<std::endl;


    std::cout<<"print original (unsorted) list"<<std::endl;
    for(const auto & i:*pL)
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;


    //sort list
    pL->sort();


    std::cout<<"print sorted list"<<std::endl;
    for(const auto & i:*pL)
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;


    delete pL;

}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSVIV.png)